# SharePoint permission level to modify metadata (properties) but not the document

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

Is it possible to implement a custom permission level that allows a user to modify the properies of a document, but not the document itself? If so, any hints on how to do it?

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to assign column level permissions in a default implementation of Sharepoint. However, it should be possible to do it using custom solutions. Have a look at this article http://www.infoq.com/articles/Dressel-Gogolowicz-wss-security. I have not tried it though.